# Is there a Java tool to reduce the visibility of methods

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a legacy code base that I want to refactor to reduce the visibility of methods to the minimum possible (private, protected, default) such that the code still works. Many of the methods in the codebase are unnecessarily public, and I'd like to change that to reduce the interface burden and simplify documentation as the code evolves in the future. Is there a tool that will analyze the codebase and generate a list of suggested methods whose visibility can be reduced? I can specify all the entry points into the code (just the main methods), and the codebase doesn't use reflection.

An Eclipse plugin will be even better.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816405/is-there-a-tool-in-eclipse-a-plugin-for-eclipse-or-an-external-program-that-ca

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816405/is-there-a-tool-in-eclipse-a-plugin-for-eclipse-or-an-external-program-that-ca/17979596#17979596

Comment: Have you tried Intellij? It suggests such changes by default.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at UCDetector (Unnecessary Code Detector - pronounced "You See Detector")
http://www.ucdetector.org/
It is an eclipse plugin and it helps to reduce visibility. I have used it for long time and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are tools that you can use to report the occurrence of methods which visibility can be reduced, I am not aware of something that allows you to transform the code to solve those issues.

However, you may find interesting taking a look to [JTransformer](https://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/jtransformer/start) and [Ekeko](https://github.com/cderoove/damp.ekeko).
Both allows you to query and accomplish custom code transformations based on logic programming techniques.  JTransformer may be a bit more mature, but Ekeko also looks quite interesting. To the best of my knowledge they both are open source and include an Eclipse plugin.